# How to show a loading state before show the complete page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, highcharts

I am using highcharts. Some of my charts needs heavy calculations that would need about 1 minute to complete. As you know in highcharts we make our charts as a model and pass it to our view. I want that the view be loaded and show a loading picture and when the background calculation is done receive the model and show the charts.

Means I want my view be shown but also be await to receive a model.

How to handle this in asp.net mvc4 and c#?

Or any other ways...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is this:

In my view I check that is the model null or not.

If the model be null I will send an ajax request to a method in my controller to calculate.

While this is going I am showing a page whith a div containing `Please wait,Loadin...` message.

Then the calculation method saved the calculation result in a `TempDate` and in success function I will refresh the view.

In the controller for this view I will pass the `TempDate` to the view.

```
public ActionResult Chart()
{
    var chart=TempData["chart"];
    return View(chart);
}
```

Chart view:

```
@model DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
@if (Model != null)
{
<script src="~/Scripts/highcharts.src.js"></script>
@(Model)
}
else
{
<h3 style="text-align:center">Loadin...</h3>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.getJSON("/WebServices/DrawChart",function(){
                window.location.replace("/WebServices/ChancePreview");
            })
        });
    </script>
}
```

And Finally:

```
public JsonResult DrawChart()
{
    //Calculations goes here...
    TempData["chart"]=chart;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is what i'd prefer,

Highcharts provides an option to show loading.

can be done with options provided in

options in api provided [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#loading)

you can use  `showLoading()` and `hideLoading()` methods to dynamically show and hide the test.

so you can start the loading indicator when the calculations initiate and then hide it after displaying the chart

here is a [example](http://jsfiddle.net/kolliparavamsikrishna/Q5krC/) which I hope would work for you.

Comment: Good thing but just one problem.I am using nuget highcharts.There the chart is provided server side in controller.And the problem is that before finishing the calculations nothing would be return as View().